# Can't access to my FTP through windows but on linux it works,may anyone help?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I set up a FTP using pasv mode since I don't have the permission for 20&21, the weird thing is I can access to my FTP on linux but it says i don't have the permission if i use windows even if i use the same account.I'm totally a newb on this so i don't know what to do and i can't find any helpful sugguestions through internet.Any suggestions will be apprecaited!
I've download vsftpd on ubuntu22.04.3 and set the condf like this:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enbale=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=14002
pasv_max_port=15000
listen_port=14001
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

I'm sure i've put my user name into the userlist and
I use `sudo service vsftpd status` to check its status and I'm sure it's working properly but when I want to access it on windows it'll say
'200 switching to binary mode' and '227 entering passive mode' also tell me to check if i have the permission to upload files.
I also tried using linux to access and i think it works, i can access to it and i can make a new folder.
I really have no ideas about this now,may anyone help? I'd be appreciated for that,thanks!

Comment: Did you make sure your FTP client on Windows was configured to connect with a PASV connection so it can reach your FTP server?

Comment: Thanks for answering. My cilent on Windows is configured to connect with PASV connection so I think there must be something else went wrong. And I've finally found the solution, I add a line in the vsftpd.conf which says `pasv_address=[my server address]`  then it works well.